# Can I pull XCOM value to ssh_conn_id in SSHOperator in Airflow

Tags: airflow, jinja2, airflow-xcom

Im Trying to dynimically assign the ssh_conn_id using the xcom value I pushed in a previous task. Here is my code.

```
def get_config_params(**kwargs):
    ti = kwargs['ti']
    ti.xcom_push(key='myServer1', value='SSH_CONN_1')
    ti.xcom_push(key='myValue', value='Hello World')

with DAG(
    dag_id=DAG_ID, 
    catchup=False,
    schedule_interval=None,
    start_date=DAG_START_DATE,
    default_args={'owner':DAG_OWNER}
) as dag:

    get_param_task  = PythonOperator(
        task_id='get_param_task',
        python_callable=get_config_params,
        provide_context=True
    )
    cli_command = SSHOperator(
        task_id="cli_command",
        ssh_conn_id='{{ ti.xcom_pull(key="myServer1") }}',
        command='echo {{ ti.xcom_pull(key="myValue") }}'
    )
```

But i'm getting the following error:

```
SSH operator error: The conn_id `{{ ti.xcom_pull(key="myServer1") }}` isn't defined
```

XCOM pull for the command in the task is working fine, but its not working for the ssh_conn_id. Is there any workaround for this?

I Also tried pulling with task id as well but still facing the same issue.

```
 cli_command2 = SSHOperator(
        task_id="cli_command2",
        ssh_conn_id='{{ ti.xcom_pull(task_ids="get_param_task",key="myServer1") }}',
        command='echo "Hello world"'
    )
```

Still getting the error:

```
SSH operator error: The conn_id `{{ ti.xcom_pull(task_ids="get_param_task",key="myServer1") }}` isn't defined
```

Comment: It's not exposed as [`template_fields`](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-ssh/stable/_modules/airflow/providers/ssh/operators/ssh.html#SSHOperator). You may try to define your custom operator inheriting from `SSHOperator` and declare this property as template field. Also note that you may use [`task.output`](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/tutorial/taskflow.html#consuming-xcoms-between-decorated-and-traditional-tasks) to pass XCom values

Comment: Thank You! I was able to make the ssh_conn_id a template field using the following code:

class SSHOperator(SSHOperator):
    template_fields = (
        "ssh_conn_id",
    ) + SSHOperator.template_fields

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this by making the ssh_conn_id a template field using the following code:

```
class SSHOperator(SSHOperator):
template_fields = (
    "ssh_conn_id",
) + SSHOperator.template_fields
```